# Are the datasets is all the same in the huggingface?

Tags: python, large-language-model, ag

huggingface_hub.utils._errors.HfHubHTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://hf-mirror.com/api/datasets/ag_news/ag_news.py

When I am training my Model, there exists a problem like this. However, the other datasets such as sst2 and MIND do not have this problem.